# How can I create a custom font service for Persian language

Tags: fonts, right-to-left, replace, persian

Hi
There are very limited Persian fonts for the websites, I need to know if there is a way to have custom fonts loaded in websites ?
There are some font replacement services but I dont know if they work with RTL languages like Persian or not 
Also I would like to collaborate with someone who is interested in this project :)
Regards

Answer (score 3):

@font-face does work with Persian fonts. However, browsers are quite buggy. Macs will generally require AAT tables in addition to OpenType, and Chrome tends not to do the Arabic script layout at all. The Chrome [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27131) is expected to be fixed soon.

http://farsitel.com/fa/ is one site that does use a web font (their "Iranian Sans" is based on DejaVu).

Monotype's [webfonts.fonts.com](http://webfonts.fonts.com/Project/ChooseFonts?Languages=W20) has a number of Arabic script fonts as well, subject to similar limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so you say the best way is to use font-face ?
There are some paid services out there, what about them ? are they better or not ?
If they are good, i want to make such a service for persian fonts...
Whats your opinion ?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

this  service make easier use persian font 
 can use [persian font api](http://www.font-api.ir/)